# How to raise a matrix to a power with double pointers in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, matrix

I am trying to raise a matrix to a power, **using pointers** but there is a mistake in my code I can't find.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
>
int **alloc(int r, int c) {
    int **d;

    d = (int **)malloc(r * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        d[i] = (int *)malloc(c * sizeof(int));
    }
    return d;
void input(int **A, int r, int c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            printf("[%d][%d]=", i, j);
            scanf_s("%d", &A[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
void output(int **A, int r, int c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            printf("%d ", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void power(int **A,int**D, int r, int c,int p) {
    int i, j,k;
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            D[i][j] = A[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    while (p) {
      // this is the matrix multiplication, where I attempt to multiply my matrix A with itself, and store the result in D, which initially started as A's copy, and p is the power I'm raising it to.
        for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {

                for (k = 0; k < c; k++)
                    D[i][j] = D[i][j] + A[i][k] * D[k][j];
            }
        }
        p--;
    }
} 
void main() {
    int r, c;
    int **A, **D;

    printf("rows A: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &r);
    printf("columns A: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &c);
    
    A = alloc(r, c);
    

    printf("\nValues of A:\n");
    input(A, r, c);
    printf("\nMatrIX A is:\n");
    output(A, r, c);


    D = alloc(r, c);
    printf("input the value you want to raise your matrix to: ");
    int p;
    scanf_s("%d", &p);
    power(A, D, r, c, p);
    printf("\nMatrix raised to said power is:\n");
    output(D, r, c);

    _getch();
}
```

When I input the rows and columns as 2 each, and input all values in the matrix as 1 and raise it to the power of 3, my answer should be

```
4 4
4 4
```

instead of

```
72 72
232 232
```

What is wrong in my code? If I were to print the D matrix before the multiplication, it would print it correctly, as:

```
1 1
1 1
```

Comment: Don't you need a square matrix if you want to raise it to a power? (Your example input is, but I think that should be part of your program.) A square matrix would probably also get rid of the index confusion you have in your multiplication: You can multiply an m×n matrix with an n×p matrix and your variable `k` must iterate over the common dimension. Finally, you multiply once too often: **A** ¹ = **A**, but you multiply it with itself. (There's also the case of **A** ⁰ = **I**.)

Comment: You're also "pulling out the rug" from under **D** : You assign to it and read from it at the same time. That can't be good.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I was indeed multiplying it too often. I removed the third for, and switched the while(p) to while(p>1) and now it does what it should have done. 
I'll test for square matrix and power of 0 now, firstly I just needed to see it work.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure how you manage without the third loop. Each element in the result matrix is a sum over the corresponding row of the first and the column of the second matrix. By the way, I think [[2, 2], [2, 2]]³ should be [[32, 32], [32, 32]], not [[4, 4], [4, 4]].

Comment: I messed up, deleting the third loop only works for my example, which is [[1,1],[1,1]]. Overjoyed with a good answer, I didn't check for others. Could you give me an example on how you'd fix this?

Comment: (Okay, I now see that your example input is [[1, 1,], [1, 1]] ³, which should indeed be [[4, 4], [4, 4]]. Sorry about that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two-step allocation looks okay, except that you don't free the memory after you're done. Your problem is in how you multiply the matrix:

- Raising a matrix to a power involves multiplying it to itself. You can only do that if the matrix is square. You can replace all occurrences of rows `r` and columns `c` with a single dimension `n`.
- When you do the actual multiplication:

  ```
   D[i][j] = D[i][j] + A[i][k] * D[k][j];
  ```

  you assign to `D` and read from it at the same time. Subsequent calculations (of the same multiplication) will see a changed value of `D[i][j]`. You will need a temporary "scratch" matrix.
- Your code multiplies once too many. Also, Raising a matrix to the power of zero should yield the identity matrix.

Here's how your `power` function could look like:

```
void power(int **A, int **D, int n, int p)
{
    int i, j,k;

    // assign identity matrix to result D

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            D[i][j] = (i == j);
        }
    }
    
    // create a scratch matrix
    
    int **tmp = alloc(n);
    
    while (p-- > 0) {
    
        // multiply [tmp] = [A] * [D]
    
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                tmp[i][j] = 0;

                for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
                    tmp[i][j] += A[i][k] * D[k][j];
            }
        }
        
        // copy [D] = [tmp]
        
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                D[i][j] = tmp[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    
    // TODO: clean up the scratch matrix
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I've never seen  `D[i][j] = (i == j);` , what does it do?

Comment: All comparison operators such as `==` or `<` return either 0 or 1. That's a terse, but perhaps overly fancy way of writing `if (i == j) D[i][j] = 1; else D[i][j] = 0;` (The parentheses are not strictly necesary, but I like to include them when I use comparisons outside `if`, `while` and `for`.)